# Creating sort visualiser in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

I'm trying to make a sort visualiser using Ruby and Gosu. When the user left clicks it will sort the numbers out using a insertion sort. When the user right clicks it will sort the numbers out using a bubble sort. So far the only the insertion sort works but the bubble sort crashes after sorting out the first number. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

```
        require 'gosu'

        module ZOrder
          BACKGROUND, MIDDLE, TOP = *0..2
        end

        SCREEN_WIDTH = 600  # needs to be COUNT * COLUMN_WIDTH
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200 # Should be multiple of 100
        MAX_VALUE = 100 # the range of the data 1 to 100
        COUNT = 30 # Number of items
        COL_WIDTH = 20  # suggested at least 10

        class Column
          # have a pointer to the neighbouring cells
          attr_accessor :height, :value

          def initialize(value)
            @value = value
            @height = (SCREEN_HEIGHT/MAX_VALUE) * value
          end
        end

        class GameWindow < Gosu::Window

          def initialize
            super SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, false
            self.caption = "Sort Visualiser"
            @path = nil
            @do_insert = false
            @do_bubble = false

            @columns = Array.new(COUNT)

            column_index = 0
            while (column_index < COUNT)
              col = Column.new(rand(MAX_VALUE + 1))
              @columns[column_index] = col
              column_index += 1
            end
            @text_font = Gosu::Font.new(10)
          end

          def needs_cursor?
            true
          end

          def insertion_sort(loop)
             j = loop
             done = false
             while ((j > 0) and (!done))
               if (@columns[j].value < @columns[j - 1].value)
                 temp = @columns[j - 1]
                 @columns[j - 1] = @columns[j]
                 @columns[j] = temp
               else
                 done = true
               end
               j = j - 1
             end
          end

            def bubble_sort(loop2)
                j = loop2
                i = loop2 + 1
                done = false
                while ((j > 0) and (!done))
                if (@columns[j].value > @columns[i].value)
                    temp = @columns[j]
                    @columns[j] = @columns[i]
                    @columns[i] = temp  
                else            
                    done = true
                end
                j = j - 1
                end
            end

          def button_down(id)
            case id
              when Gosu::MsLeft
                @do_insert = true
                @loop = 0
                @do_bubble = false
              when Gosu::MsRight
                @do_bubble = true
                @loop2 = 0
                @do_insert = false
              end
          end


          def update
                if (@do_insert)
                  puts "Doing insert #{@loop}"
                  if @loop < (COUNT)
                    insertion_sort(@loop)
                    @loop += 1
                    sleep(0.5)
                  else
                    @do_insert = false
                  end
                end

                if (@do_bubble)
                    puts "Doing bubble #{@loop2}"
                    if @loop2 < (COUNT)
                        bubble_sort(@loop2)
                        @loop2 += 1
                        sleep(0.5)
                    else
                        @do_bubble = false
                    end
                end
            end


          def draw
            column_index = 0
            while (column_index < @columns.length)
              color = Gosu::Color::GREEN
              Gosu.draw_rect((column_index * COL_WIDTH), SCREEN_HEIGHT - @columns[column_index].height, COL_WIDTH, @columns[column_index].height, color, ZOrder::MIDDLE, mode=:default)
              @text_font.draw("#{@columns[column_index].value}", (column_index * COL_WIDTH) + 5, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 10, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::RED)
              column_index += 1
            end
          end
        end

        window = GameWindow.new
        window.show
```

EDIT: Added in the rest of the code and removed some tags

Comment: Ruby is a safe programming language, a Ruby program cannot possibly crash. If it *does* crash, it's a bug in the interpreter, not in your code. Ruby programs *may* raise exceptions or not terminate, but they simply do not crash, ever.

Comment: By my reading you are asking why your bubble sort code is not working correctly. If that's the case please strip out all references and code related to insertion sort and visualization (including that in the title), as that is irrelevant. Also, there is no main method which, presumably would initialize the instance variables. It's difficult to answer your question without knowing, for example, what `@columns[i].value` means.